# How can I find prime numbers through bit operations in C++?

Tags: c++, math, primes

How can I find prime numbers through bit operations in C++?

Comment: What do you mean by "find prime number"? Do you mean generate primes or test to see if a given number is prime? What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Was this a take home question or are you looking for what the right answer "would" have been? I can see the latter as being more valuable to the community that the former.

Comment: I mean to test if a number is prime. I know how to implement this in normal math but using bit operations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try implementing a [prime sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) using a bitset. The algorithm only needs to store whether a certain number is a prime or not. One bit is sufficient for that.

Comment: I agree.  this seems like precisely what the teacher was asking.

Answer (score 15):

I think the way to do this is to not think of the bitset as its numerical representation as we normally do, but to think of it at a list of numbers.  So the bitset

```
1111
```

would represent the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Now if we say that a '1' represents prime and a '0' represents not prime, we can make a sieve as follows.

Set all the bits to 1 (I'm going to use 16 bits that represent the integers 1 through 16)

```
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

I know that one is not prime, so I'm setting it to zero.

```
0111 1111 1111 1111
```

Now, I know that the next '1' I encounter represents a prime, but all multiples of that number are by definition *not* prime, so I leave the next '1' alone, but set all of its multiples to '0'.  Since the next '1' represents the number 2, I zero every second bit.

```
0110 1010 1010 1010
```

The benefit of this method over others is that as I traverse the rest of the bits, I don't need to check each one to see if it's divisible by 2 (so nothing like `if i % 2 == 0` is necessary).  I can just keep incrementing the index by 2 and I know I'll always land on a non-prime.

Now I just do the same thing again with the next '1' I encounter (the next prime starting from the last prime I identified, 2).  I know it's prime, since it isn't divisible by any of the numbers below it.  I know all of its multiples are prime, so since it's in the third position, I set every third following bit to '0'.  Some of them are already '0' since they're also multiples of 2.  That's okay, just leave them '0'.

```
0110 1010 0010 1000
```

The next '1' that you encounter is the fifth bit.  Now you *could* keep going until you reach the end, but since 5 is greater than the square root of the number of bits that I started with, I know I'm not going to find any more composites, so I'm done.

---

After a little more searching I found a really good implementation example in Deitel & Deitel's [C++ How to Program](http://books.google.com/books?id=HhGB8fOiUy8C&pg=RA2-PA132&lpg=RA2-PA132&dq=test+if+number+is+prime+using+bitset&source=bl&ots=wOeGo29Tfg&sig=QxFsYkfB9dLyOCVP6SaQ6ihZzl4&hl=en&ei=OO0XSrjcLaOxtgei3-X2DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#PRA2-PA133,M1).  They also provide good explanations of the algorithm and code.

Comment: 8.5 years later I stumbled on to this. Good stuff! 

For a python implementation that works blazingly fast see    [Edit #5] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901856/1968829)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know, then getting the answer from someone else is kind of cheating, no? Tell the guy you don't know. It's ok not to know every question in an interview. It looks far worse to be caught cheating or copying stuff than saying "i don't know." Explain how you know what a prime number is, explain some properties of prime numbers and explain what you know about bit operations. If you don't know these things, then maybe this job isn't for you?

Comment: I don't think he's in that interview while he's asking here, so giving him the answer now is considered learning, not cheating.

Comment: The desperation in the tone of the question (now edited out) led me to believe that this is a remote or offline interview.

Comment: I was not able to answer this in interview. So I am asking this here. Just to learn

Answer (score -1):

I found this c# code, I am sure you can read it well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace eratosthenes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 100;
            bool[] primes = new bool[n];
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                primes[i]=true;
            }

            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (primes[i] == true) {
                    for (int j = i * i; j < n; j=j+i)
                    {
                        primes[j] = false;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The link to [german wikibooks page](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Primzahlen:_Programmbeispiele#C.23).

Comment: It doesn't use bit operations to achieve it, though. Also, don't copy code without linking back to the source.