# Stoping generator in first answer, use return instead

Tags: python, prolog, yield, prolog-cut

I am using too much to my taste the pattern (after every possible solution branch of the search). This is the code to find boggle words in given square. It had a bug if the words are not preselected to include only those whose letter pairs are neighbours, which I fixed now by changing comparrision not pos to pos is None.

```
def word_path(word,used=[],pos=None):
    if not word:
        yield False
        return
    else:
        correct_neighbour = [neigh for p,neigh in neighbour_set
                  if (not pos or pos==p) and (neigh not in used) and boggle[neigh]==word[0] ]
        for i in correct_neighbour:
            used_copy=used[:]+[i]
            if boggle[i]==word:
                yield used_copy
                return
            else:
                for solution in  word_path(word[1:],used_copy,pos=i) or (False,):
                    if solution:
                        yield solution
                    return
```

Is there any better alternative to make generator which stops after any answer was found?

**Solution based on why not use return**

Finally it got me and returned sequence is iterator no matter that it was returned not yielded value. so I changed my word_path code to use return and cleaned up the expressions generally. Instead of giving None or False the function returns (False,). Then I have not problem with None not accepted for for statement.

```
def word_path(word,used=[],pos=None):
if word:
    correct_neighbour = [neigh
                         for p,neigh in neighbour_set
                         if ((pos is None or pos==p) and
                             (neigh not in used) and
                             boggle[neigh]==word[0]
                             )
                         ]
    for i in correct_neighbour:
        used_copy=used[:]+[i]
        if len(word)==1:
            if boggle[i]==word:
                return (used_copy,)
        else:
            for solution in  word_path(word[1:],used_copy,pos=i):
                if solution:
                    return (solution,)
return (False,)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yielding until all needed values are yielded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324947/yielding-until-all-needed-values-are-yielded)

Comment: @S.Lott: It isn't a duplicate. This question wants to stop producing at some point, whereas the alleged duplicate wants the caller to stop the generator when it wants to stop consuming.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. While not exactly common, it is perfectly normal and OK to return immediately after a yield to signal that there are no more values forthcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you make it a generator in the first place when you only want one answer? Just search for answers and return the first one instead of yielding it.

Answer (score 1):

```
return iter([anwser])
```