# Runtime Crash For A Very Basic Python Program

Tags: python, crash

I work on a windows XP PC with a Python 2.6 install and I was trying to solve a Project Euler problem, but whenever I execute the code the interpreter hangs. I've debugged it through PyScripter, IDLE and MonkeyStudio, but it still doesn't work even for trivial values like 15.

I simply don't understand why. Can you please help me out?

Here's the code:

```
"""Project Euler Problem 3
Author: A"""

num = 15
prime = [1]
x = long (round(num/2))

def ifprime (x): 
        """ Defining the function that checks if the number is prime or not"""    
        """ Checking if the passed number is prime or not"""

        y = long(round(x/2))
        while y > 0:
                if x%y == 0:
                        return False
                y -= 1
        return True

while x > 0:
    if num%x == 0:
        if ifprime(x):
                print "I've found a prime! "
                print x
                prime[len(prime):] = [x]
        x -= 1
```

Comment: You say you tried debugging it... Can't you find where it's going wrong on your own? (I did, and it's pretty obvious what's going on)

Comment: I have no clue why I didn't see it. I just started coding a few days ago. So, that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your x -= 1 statement is indented one level too far.

x will only be decremented when num % x is 0

It should be this:

```
while x > 0:
    if num%x == 0:
        if ifprime(x):
                print "I've found a prime! "
                print x
                prime[len(prime):] = [x]
    x -= 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite loop:

`x -= 1` is never called as it's under the `num%x == 0` condition, which never happens (as `x` never changes its value).

When `num` is 15, `x` starts as 7. Then, `num % x` is 1, therefore the condition is false and `x` is not decremented - thus looping ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others have pointed out, your `ifprime` is wrong. You are checking `while y > 0`, and of course that tests up to `y = 1`, and thus will always return false.

And for optimization purposes, you don't have to test up to `x/2`, you can test up to `sqrt(x)` and that's good enough.

```
import math

def ifprime (x): 

    y = math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))

    while y > 1:
        if x % y == 0:
            return False
        y -= 1

    return True
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that on running and I corrected it. On the other hand, the function doesn't recognize 2 as a prime if I take it as y>1. So, I have to figure that out.

Thanks a lot for the optimization trick.

Comment: @JustA: Hardcode 2 to be prime, and only check for divisibility by 2 and by odd numbers >= 3.

Comment: @Brian: I'm feeling like a retard right now. I have lots to learn.

Comment: also keep in mind that if you start at 2 and work your way up, the likelihood of getting a match (for the early-out) is much greater.

Answer (score 0):

I have [dealt so much with primes](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post1277707.html#post1277707) that I did the complement to find factor and define ifprime using that, for a change.

```
import math

## I want any which return first not False value
def some(seq):
    for item in seq:
        if item:
            return item

def factor (number):
    """ returns smallest factor of number or None """
    if number < 4: return None
    return some(divisor
                for divisor in [2] + range(3,int(number ** 0.5)+2, 2)
                if not(number % divisor))

# little slower way for fun (because factor gives the factoring it found)
def ifprime(number):
    return number > 1 and not factor(number)

print [number for number in range(100) if ifprime(number)]
```

(If you need many primes use [sieve algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285443/improving-pure-python-prime-sieve-by-recurrence-formula) instead of prime test.)