# Finding first n primes?

Tags: python, math, performance, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python)

Although I already have written a function to find all primes under n (`primes(10) -> [2, 3, 5, 7]`), I am struggling to find a quick way to find the first n primes. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Memoization is probably the fastest. ;)

Comment: Not a duplicate: OP wants the first *n* primes, not all primes below *n*.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897297/speed-up-bitstring-bit-operations-in-python

Comment: There is almost no difference between "finding the first n primes" and "finding all primes below n". Any algorithm that can find all primes below k can easily be modified to continue increasing k until n primes are found.

Comment: @TheBigO: It's not intuitive (at least not to me) how to do that efficiently - for example, wouldn't you need to do a whole lot of extra work in the sieve if you try to increase *n*? From my brief read of the algorithm it feels like you'd have to essentially restart with the new *n*.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner, fair enough. I've added an answer to address those concerns.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it's asking a different question from the proposed duplicate. First n primes vs. all primes below n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the estimate `g(n) = n log n + n log log n`*, which estimates the size of the nth prime for n > 5.

Then run a sieve on that estimate.
`g(n)` gives an overestimate, which is okay because we can simply discard the extra primes generated which are larger than the desired n.

Then consider the answers in "[Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188)".

If you are concerned about the actual runtime of the code (instead of the order of magnitude of the time complexity of the algorithm), consider using one of the solutions that use numpy (instead of one of the "pure python" solutions).

*When I write `log` I mean the natural logarithm.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to go with this... my code `primes(int(pi*n))[:n]` only returns the correct number of primes for numbers bellow 12.

Comment: Your code should run `primes(g(n))`. I'm not sure if that's what you meant. There was an error in the `g(n)` function in my answer, try again using the new function.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number), the nth prime number p_n satisfies

> p_n < n ln(n) + n ln( ln(n) )

for n >= 6

So if you run your current function (or, e.g., one of the sieves mentioned in other answers) using the next integer greater than the right-hand side above, you are guaranteed to find the nth prime.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Use the [π](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml) function to estimate what value of *n* you want to look towards, overshoot slightly, and then use a sieve to compute up to the point you need.

Comment: +1 for getting the name right, -1 for proposing the same (incorrect) solution.

Comment: @ChrisLutz I suppose I deserve it for jumping in with an answer before editing to flesh it out, but it seems reasonable to me (after my edit) to use π to estimate a reasonable overshoot and then just stop early on the way there. I'll have to see what the duplicate answer suggests. :)

Comment: I haven't done any downvoting in this question. I was being humerous as my math yields a net of zero.

Comment: @ChrisLutz I understand; I've made plenty of similar "no-vote" comments in the past. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the fastest but [Euler's Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Euler.27s_sieve) seems good.

EDIT

As the other answers is suggesting you can use basic facts on the prime number theorem2. Or you can learn basic algebraic geometry and use elliptic curve primality testing.

Comment: That's another method for finding primes under n.

Comment: I have seen about 172 primes under n functions, I am looking for a first n primes code.

Answer (score 0):

Use sieve of Erastothrones using the fact that prime numbers are either of the form 6n+1 or 6n-1 after 2 and 3.This will improve the speed of the program