# Fastest mutable data holder

Tags: python, arrays, primes

I recently downloaded the bitarray module from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bitarray,), for a faster prime sieve, but the results are dismal.

---

```
from bitarray import bitarray
from numpy import ones
from timeit import timeit


def sieve1(n = 1000000):
    '''Sieve of Eratosthenes (bitarray)'''
    l = (n - 1)/2; a = bitarray(l); a.setall(True)
    for i in xrange(500):
        if a[i]:
            s = i+i+3; t = (s*s-3)/2; a[t:l:s] = False
    return [2] + [x+x+3 for x in xrange(l) if a[x]]

def sieve2(n = 1000000):
    '''Sieve of Eratosthenes (list)'''
    l = (n - 1)/2; a = [True] * l
    for i in xrange(500):
        if a[i]:
            s = i+i+3; t = (s*s-3)/2; u = l-t-1
            a[t:l:s] = [False] * (u/s + 1)
    return [2] + [x+x+3 for x in xrange(l)]

def sieve3(n = 1000000):
    '''Sieve of Eratosthenes (numpy.ones)'''    
    l = (n - 1)/2; a = ones(l, dtype=bool)
    for i in xrange(500):
        if a[i]:
            s = i+i+3; t = (s*s-3)/2; a[t:l:s] = False
    return [2] + [x+x+3 for x in xrange(l)]

print timeit(sieve1, number=10)
print timeit(sieve2, number=10)
print timeit(sieve3, number=10)
```

---

Here are the result -

```
1.59695601594
0.666230770593
0.523708537583
```

---

The `bitarray` sieve is more than twice as slow as a list.
Does anyone have suggestions for better arrays? Anything should be faster than a python `list`, or so I thought.
`numpy.ones` is fastest, but I don't like `numpy` since it takes a long time to `import` it.

I'm basically looking for a fast data-holder, which is mutable, and can hold `True` and `False`.

Comment: I don't know what the state of the art is, but maybe a more sophisticated algorithm is the way to get better performance? Wikipedia mentions a couple.

Comment: @NPE, even a more sophisticated algorithm will require a fast mutable data-holder. having said that, I'm still working on a sieve which does not store multiples of 3.

Comment: Sure. I was just suggesting a different line of attack.

Comment: Bitarrays are memory optimized as they store many bits in a byte. That being set, accessing single bits is going to be slow, since the whole byte has to be read, modified, and stored. For python lists or numpy arrays, bytes are only written.

Comment: Isn't a numpy `bool` array already a bit array?

Comment: @DanielFischer numpy `bool` uses a whole byte for each entry, possibly for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: @kjb Aha, thanks. I've always found the boost due to the better locality outweigh the extra cycles for masking and shifting, but I guess that effect does not unconditionally hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual setting and clearing of bits is very fast in bitarray. What is making is slower building the return list. Instead of iterating through a range, and then testing each bit, take advantage of bitarray's support of iterating through the bits.

Try this:

```
def bitarray_sieve(n = 1000000):
    '''Sieve of Eratosthenes (bitarray)'''
    l = (n - 1)//2; a = bitarray(l); a.setall(True)
    for i in range(500):
        if a[i]:
            s = i+i+3; t = (s*s-3)//2; a[t:l:s] = False
    return [2] + [x+x+3 for x,b in enumerate(a) if b]
```

It runs in about 0.38 seconds on my machine while the list version takes about 0.47 seconds.

Have you looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897297/speed-up-bitstring-bit-operations-in-python/2903765#2903765)?

I maintain gmpy2 and I added the ability to iterate over the bits in an integer and to set/clear bits.

The following example takes about 0.16 seconds.

```
def gmpy2_sieve2(n=1000000):
    '''Sieve of Eratosthenes (gmpy2, version 2)'''
    l = (n - 1)//2; a = gmpy2.xbit_mask(l)
    for i in range(500):
        if a[i]:
            s = i+i+3; t = (s*s-3)//2; u = l-t-1
            a[t:l:s] = 0
    return [2] + [x+x+3 for x in a.iter_set()]
```

The bottleneck is now the calculation `x+x+3`. The following solution doesn't skip sieving 2. It takes twice as much memory but it allow the bit positions to be used immediately. It takes about 0.08 seconds on my machine:

```
def gmpy2_sieve(limit=1000000):
    '''Returns a generator that yields the prime numbers up to limit.

    Bits are set to 1 if their position is composite.'''

    sieve_limit = gmpy2.isqrt(limit) + 1
    limit += 1

    # Mark bit positions 0 and 1 as not prime.
    bitmap = gmpy2.xmpz(3)

    # Process 2 separately. This allows us to use p+p for the step size
    # when sieving the remaining primes.
    bitmap[4 : limit : 2] = -1

    # Sieve the remaining primes.
    for p in bitmap.iter_clear(3, sieve_limit):
        bitmap[p*p : limit : p+p] = -1

    return list(bitmap.iter_clear(2, limit))
```

For the actual setting/clearing of the bits, bitarray is faster than gmpy2. And bitarray has many capabilities that gmpy2 lacks. However, I couldn't find a faster method in bitarrary to get the index of which bits are set or clear.

BTW, your benchmark functions sieve2() and sieve3() return incorrect results; you are missing `if a[x]`.